# Entity framework: Nesting same context says connection already open

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have a piece of code that needs to return me a delimited string on basis of data from a DB, all runs fine except for the line against which comment is mentioned.
I know the fact that single DbContext can not be used for multiple QUERIES at single instance of time.

```
private string FetchNewEmployees(DateTime addedAfter)
    {
        StringBuilder newEmployees = new StringBuilder();
        using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var employees = dbContext.Student.Where(p => p.lastupdatedon > addedAfter);
            foreach (var employee in employees)
            {
                newEmployees.Append(string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}|{4}{5}",
                    employee.Name,
                    employee.DOB,
                    employee.department.DepartmentName, // This line throws error saying connection already open | commenting this makes it work like charm
                    employee.EMailAddress,
                    employee.SchoolName,
                    System.Environment.NewLine));
            }
        }
        return newEmployees.ToString();
    }
```

The problem id, "department" is another table, hence a foreign key for "employee"...
In case I am unclear, let me know.

Any help right now will be like winning two worlds for me :)

Comment: Have you got `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in the connection string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First workaround:

```
var employees = dbContext.Student.Where(p => p.lastupdatedon > addedAfter).ToList();
...
```

This closes the connection to the student table but will generate additional queries to lazy load departments.

Another option:

```
var employees = dbContext.Student.Include( s => s.department ).Where(p => p.lastupdatedon > addedAfter);
...
```

This causes a single query to be generated which joins both tables.